# Is there a cleaner and a shorter way to write this conditional in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, conditional-operator

```
>>> def accept(d1, d2):
    if somefunc(d1,d2) > 32:
        h = 1
    else:
        h = 0
    return h
```

[Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python) doesn't give a solution for a case one want to return a value. A lambda based solution is preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, perhaps trickier,

```
return int(somefunc(d1, d2) > 32)
```

Note that `int(True) == 1` and `int(False) == 0`.

Comment: Actually you could just return `somefunc(d1, d2) > 32` directly, since True and False already are `int`s.

Comment: But that wouldn't return **exactly** what their original code returned.  For all we know, someone on the receiving end is doing a `type()` check on the results ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The "return-value scenario" is no different than any other:

```
return 1 if somefunc(d1, d2) > 32 else 0
```

If for some reason you want a lambda:

```
lambda d1, d2: 1 if somefunc(d1, d2) > 32 else 0
```

Note that a lambda is no different than a function defined with `def` that returns the same thing. Lambdas are just regular functions.

Answer (score -1):

Turn into a `lambda` (not a explicit function):

```
accept = lambda d1,d2: 1 if somefunc(d1, d2) > 32 else 0
```

Comment: A lambda is a function.